# TextField in tableView cell is not outputting text to the console

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, textfield

I have created a tableView with two different labels and one textfield. Depending on the indexPath in which is selected the labels will display different text according to the array. I have created a CocoTouch Class file and made it type TableViewCell.

**TableViewCell.swift**

```
import UIKit
class Driver_Navigation_TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var orderTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var adressLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!



    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }


    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
}
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController, MGLMapViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

        var allCellsText = [String]()

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    array.count
        }
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! Driver_Navigation_TableViewCell

        cell.adressLabel.text = passengersAdress[indexPath.row]
        cell.nameLabel.text = passengersName[indexPath.row]
        cell.orderTextField.placeholder = "\(indexPath.row + 1)."
        return(cell)
    }
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! Driver_Navigation_TableViewCell

cell.orderTextField.tag = indexPath.row

cell.orderTextField.delegate = self // theField is your IBOutlet UITextfield in your custom cell

return cell
}
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    allCellsText.append(textField.text!)
    print(allCellsText)
}
    }
```

Comment: Use a breakpoint and check if the text field delegate is called. If it is check what the `textField.text` is.

Comment: I know how to create a breakpoint, but how do you see if the textField delegate is called. And textField is parameter that is passed in.

Comment: If you text field resignsFirstResponder and your breakpoint is not called, then your delegate was not called.

Answer (score 0):

You cant have **duplicate** `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate methods` it won't work like that.

Also in your code you have not set the delegate for the textField in both the cellForRowAtIndexPath() methods.

If you want to have two table view in a single controller try the following

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return array.count   
  }
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! Driver_Navigation_TableViewCell

      if tableView == self.tableView1 {
        cell.adressLabel.text = passengersAdress[indexPath.row]
        cell.nameLabel.text = passengersName[indexPath.row]
        cell.orderTextField.placeholder = "\(indexPath.row + 1)."
       }
      else {
        cell.orderTextField.tag = indexPath.row

       }
        cell.orderTextField.delegate = self 

        return(cell)
    }
```

Create outlets for the Table View

Comment: I'm not trying to create two tableViews. I want to get the text that is inputed from the textField from the tableView cell.

Comment: @JacobKantor he is right. You are implementing the same delegate with different signatures. Do not do that. Although i do no understand what the if tableView check is for.

Comment: @ Jacob Kantor set the textfield delegate in both the methods